# How to return int and string in PHP Json API output?

Tags: php, json, api

I am new in PHP Json. May I know how to return int and string value in one PHP JSON API output? I want to return category name, category image in string but category ID in int. Please help. Thank you.

Sample code as below:-

**Category.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Category extends CI_Controller {
// ~/category/main
    public function main() {

        $this->load->model("Category_model");
        $result = $this->Category_model->getCategoryMain();
        if (count($result) == 0) {
            echo json_encode('Error');
        } else {
            echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }
    }
}
```

**Category_model.php**

```
<?php

class Category_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }
// ~/category/main
    public function getCategoryMain() {
        $sql = "select c.name, c.image, c.category_id from category c left join product p on p.category_id = c.category_id";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        $records = $result->result_array();
        return $records;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typecast the `category_id` with `(int)` or its `intval()` value:

```
public function getCategoryMain() {
    $sql = "select c.name, c.image, c.category_id from category c left join product p on p.category_id = c.category_id";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $records = array();
    foreach( $result->result_array() as $r ) {
        $r['category_id'] = intval( $r['category_id'] );
        $records[] = $r;
    }
    return $records;
}
```

Comment: Hi @the wolf, your solution is works! But may I know how to use (int) in your example for better performance?

Comment: Also, If I got multiple fields need to change to int, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this type convention is your db driver. If you use Postgres database you get the exact data format.

Btw You can do like this, easily.

```
        public function getCategoryMain() {
            $sql = "select c.name, c.image, c.category_id from category c left join product p on p.category_id = c.category_id";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);

            //$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //edited


           foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
           {
               $row['category_id']=(int) $row['category_id'];

           }

        }
```

Comment: I hit this error message when try to apply this code :- `<p>Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()</p>`

Comment: fetch_assoc() is not a method of Codeignetor query builder it's actaullay method of mysqli but you are use "Codeignetor query builder". It's my mistake to not to figure it out

Comment: Hi @dilusha, thanks for your update but what The Wolf posted is works for me. So I marked his answer. Sorry and thanks for your help!

Comment: it's ok. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Use (int) or intval() can both work, but for the performance cast (int) is better.

there's a comparison [here](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/php-casting-vs-intval/)